# linux wget download tar.gz as html?

Tags: linux, file, download, wget

I know the problem may seem naive to most of you but I couldn't find a solution. I'm using a linux virtual machine and I'm trying to download the apache-drill.tar.gz from [enter link description here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/DRILL/Apache+Drill+in+10+Minutes#ApacheDrillin10Minutes-InstallingDrillonLinux)the link (10 minutes tutorial they provide) I did the `wget "link"` but when I tried to extract the file using the `tar -xvzf` it gave me error messages as:

```
gzip:stdion:not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
Error is not recoverable; existing now
```

Initially I thought it was the file format so I `mv apache-drill.tar.gz apache-drill.tar` and `tar -xvf apache-drill.tar` but still error. (file format different)

Then I started to check the size of the file, the original .tar.gz size is 134MB but when I tried:`ls -lh apache-drill.tar.gz` it's only 34KB which is much smaller than the real tar.gz file So I'm guessing wget is not downloading the file properly. Instead of the tar it actually downloads the html for me..

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try **reading** the HTML document you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML document you downloaded consists primarily of a bunch of links to mirrors hosting the actual file.

Pick one of them and download the response.